# Error in traversing GLib Array

Tags: c

I'm having trouble retrieving values from my GArray.

```
GArray * get_leakddata(struct memory* mem) {
struct leak_data {
    char *file;
    int line;
    char *pointer;
    size_t sz;
};
```

.....

```
GArray * get_leakddata(struct memory* mem) {
    GArray *leak_array = g_array_new(false, false,sizeof(struct leak_data));
    g_hash_table_foreach(mem->metadata_hashtable,(GHFunc)get_leakdata_from_metadata, leak_array);
,struct leak_data *,3)->sz);

    return leak_array;
}

void get_leakdata_from_metadata(char *key_address, struct metadata_record *metarec, GArray *leak_array) {
    if(!get_isallocated(metarec))
        return;
    static int i=0;
    struct leak_data * ld = (struct leak_data *) malloc(sizeof(struct leak_data));
    ld->file = get_prev_file(metarec);
    ld->line = get_prev_line(metarec);
    ld->pointer = key_address;
    ld->sz = get_metadata_recordsize(metarec);

    printf("get_leakdata_from_metadata sz: %d\n",ld->sz);

    g_array_append_val(leak_array,ld);

    i++;

    printf("get_leakdata_from_metadata 2: %d\n",g_array_index(leak_array,struct leak_data*,i)->sz);

}
```

prints out:

```
get_leakdata_from_metadata sz: 12
get_leakdata_from_metadata 2: 1
```

Eventually I get a seg fault

Comment: Should it really be `struct leak_data*` in the call to `g_array_index`?

Comment: Also, your `get_leakddata` function is "garbled".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array is of `struct leak_data`s, not pointers to them. So your indexing code:

```
g_array_index(leak_array,struct leak_data*, i)->sz
```

is wrong. This is a bit surprising, but GArray really models an array, not a pointer array. There's GPtrArray for that. :) So, the above should be

```
g_array_index(leak_array, struct leak_data, i).sz
```

Comment: Thanks.  And I was just using GPtrArrays so I'm sure that confused me.